# export 'tweenManager' (imported as 'PIXI') was not found in 'pixi.js'

Tags: pixi.js

I am getting this error in react on import anyone please help.

```
import * as PIXI from "pixi.js";

ERROR in ./src/App.js 45:18-47
export 'tweenManager' (imported as 'PIXI') was not found in 'pixi.js' (possible exports: ALPHA_MODES, AbstractMultiResource, AccessibilityManage ....
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to fix the problem with imports

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
window.PIXI = PIXI;
const _PixiTween = require('pixi-tween');
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**